# How to open permissions for Deployment volumeMount mapped to EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

After creating the AWS EFS file system I went ahead and mapped it to one of the deployments/container's Volume as `/data/files` directory:

```
    volumeMounts:   
    - name: efs-persistent-storage
      mountPath: /data/files  
      readOnly: false
  volumes:
  - name: efs-persistent-storage
    nfs:
      server: fs-1234.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com 
      path: /files
```

I now am able to delete, create and modify the files stored on EFS drive. But running  .sh script that tries to copy the files fails telling that the permissions of the `/data/files` directory don't allow it to create the files.
I double checked the directory permissions. And they are all open. How could I make it work?

May be the problem is that I am mapping directly to the efs server `fs-1234.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`? Would it give me more options if I would use Persistant Volume Claim instead?

Comment: Did you try to use pv-pvc? Same access denied?

Comment: What does exactly `ls -ld /data/files` return ? Could you post the complete message that you get when trying to run the .sh script ?

Comment: You need to post your script, error, and the command you are using to execute it. If you can cp/mv/rm files from inside the pod but the script fails then make sure the script is executable.